# Big query doesn't count nulls but counts 'is not null'

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, null

Do you have any idea why this happens? This just gives me the total of ids while the count distinct of 'is not null' gives me a bit over half the ids. Clearly I have tons of null, where have they gone? :(

```
select count(distinct case when a.column1 is null then a.id end) 
   from (select ji.id as id
       , case when mh.field_id = 'value' then c.name end as column1
       , case when mh.field_id = 'value2' then mh.value end as column2
       , case when mh.field_id = 'value3' then v.name end as column3
 from `table1 ji
 join table2 mh on ji.id = mh.issue_id
 join `lotus-dev-gcp.lotus_fivetran_jira.field` f on mh.field_id = f.id
 left table3 c on mh.value  = CAST(c.id as string) 
 left join table4 v on mh.value = CAST(v.id as string) 
where mh.field_id in ('value','value2','value3')
      and ji.project = 1111
      and ji.issue_type = 222
      and mh.something = true
      group by ji.id, 2,3,4) a
```

I expected to get an accurate number of distinct ids when value is null. Instead i got something like this:

- Distinct when value is Null = 1500
- Distinct when value is Not null = 800
- Total distinct ids = 1500

Comment: Looks to me like the CASE WHEN is saying to use ID when column1 is null so then a value is returned for every record. Maybe just use `column1 IS NULL` in outer query WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query is returning multiple records for each id. Each of the 1500 ids has at least one record where column1 is NULL; 800 of the ids also have at least one record where the value is not null.

Comment: Do you know how i can change the inner query to return the correct value? meaning 1500-800. I tried adding a select distinct but it didn't help,..